# custom makefile works in cmd with Cygwin make, but not in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, makefile, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I have a simple makefile works OK under CMD prompt using Cygwin make. But have problem by invoking through Make Target in Eclipse CDT.

The content of my makefile is as below:

```
all: aaa

aaa: bbb.o
    cc -o aaa.exe bbb.o

bbb.o: bbb.c
    cc -c bbb.c

clean:
    rm -f *.exe *.o
```

When in CMD, `make all` will build and generate aaa.exe, while `make clean` will clean the EXE file generated.

The make command used is from `{myCygwinFolder}\bin\make.exe`. This can be checked by `which make` in CMD, which gives `/usr/bin/make`. Also, the Cygwin path is added in my system PATH.

But when I try to set up a Standard Make C Project, the `make clean` just doesn't work. Actually, I have setup 2 Make Targets for my project, `make all` and `make clean`. The things happened was, no matter which one I ran, I always got the following error:

```
Error launching builder (make all )
(Exec error:The system cannot find the file specified.
)
```

or

```
Error launching builder (make clean)
(Exec error:The system cannot find the file specified.
)
```

After searching online and some tries, I found it seems Eclipse couldn't find the builder/make properly.

So, I went to the project properties, Builders tab and created a new builder that point to my `{myCygwinFolder}\bin\make.exe`.

With this fix, I would be able to compile with Make Target `make all`. But when I compile with Make Target `make clean`, Eclipse still tries to run Make Target `make all`.

If I move clean section to the beginning of the makefile. Both Make Target will all run `make clean`. It seems the all/clean tags are not passed into Cygwin make correctly, and Eclipse just make the first task in makefile.

The project structure setup in Eclipse is:

```
ProjectRoot
  |__folderA
       |__makefile
       |__bbb.c
       |__*.*
  |__folderB
```

Could anyone can help in setting up correct Make Target in Eclipse? Any comments are welcomed.

Comment: See which `make.exe` is used by both - cygwin & eclipse. See the environment variables. For testing that, put some GUI application like notepad, so that make will remain waiting & not end running a bunch of commands. Then use `process explorer` to see its running directory, make.exe path, the arguments (& if required, the environment as well). If all 4 are matching, then the comamnd should work as is.

Comment: Eclipse `Make Target` name is not the same as the command you invoke. Most likely, you did not set `clean` parameter for the second command line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is path. When you are in windows environment from eclipse, you'll need to adjust the path to ensure that make can be found.  I routinely used to have to have to change the default build command to get around this back in my days of using the CDT